# How to properly align field without label on bootstrap form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="well">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="FirstName">Name</label>
            <div class="controls row-fluid">
                <div class="span2 row">
                    <input class="span12" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Firstname" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="span2 row">
                    <input class="span12" id="MiddleName" name="MiddleName" placeholder="Middlename" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="span2 row">
                    <input class="span12" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Lastname" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWGfb/

I want to add label for Last Name, so I want to have labels for First and Last Name only. How is it possible with bootstrap?

**UPDATE:**
I can make something like that:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span4">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="span4" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            // field without label
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="span4 ">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bWGfb/1/

but it adds extra margin style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="well">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
                    <input class="span12" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Firstname" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label for="MiddleName">&nbsp;</label>
                    <input class="span12" id="MiddleName" name="MiddleName" placeholder="Middlename" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label for="LastName">Last name</label>
                    <input class="span12" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Lastname" type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly, but how to remove label for Middle Name and save proper inline alignment?

Comment: Probably a bit hacky, but `<label for="MiddleName">&nbsp;</label>` will do it :P

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `label` style in `bootstrap.css` (line 946) in your own CSS

It has `5px` bottom margin, just set it to what you need, but tbh a little spacing is good ;)